# how to do HTML/CSS positioning

Tags: html, css, django

I am new to html and css so im sorry for asking this question but how do you manage more than 1 item in html? it seem so hard. i'm trying to have a image and a hover effect to it and have a text beneath this effect and then have a gallery beneath it and have it all centered. Please suggest me the ways to do so. I'll include the code i've written below and this is for a django website so some contents may be different from actual html/css.

html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>hey</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "portofolio/css/cc.css" %}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="card">
    <img src="{% static 'portofolio/img/save.png' %}" alt="Card Back">
    <img src="{% static 'portofolio/img/try.png' %}" class="img-top" alt="Card Front">
</div>
<div class="text">
    <h1>Hello. This is me</h1>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
body{
    background-color: black;
}
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.card .img-top {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.card:hover .img-top {
    display: inline;
}
.text{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'TYPOGRAPH PRO',sans-serif;
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into Css libaries like Bootstrap?

Comment: im using 2 libraries ...bootstrap as well as some template for navbar

Comment: I am confused on what you are trying to do? You seem to have some code in CSS that can be enhanced to solve your problem. Where is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that wen i add a new element like image or text or somehing ....it gets positioned wrong. and wen i load my nav bar same thing happnes